# Converting double to string function - memory issues?

Tags: c++, double, stdstring, memory-efficient

I find myself having to std::cout various double variables.
I've made a simple function to convert a double to a std::string, which I can then use with std::cout etc.

```
// Convert a double to a string.
std::string dtos(double x) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << x;
    return s.str();
}
```

The function seems to work OK, but my question is: does this approach have any (bad) memory implications ie. am I allocating unecessary memory, or leaving anything 'dangling'?

Thanks guys
Pete

Comment: you don't have to convert a double to a string for std::cout or other stream objects

Comment: @named: Thanks, but the method won't compile if I return s. Do you mean change the function signature too to std::stringstream? Or?

Comment: @miguel.martin - sorry, I meant string manipulation eg. s + "\n" + x etc.

Comment: @Pete855217 Ignore me please. For some reason I was thinking that s is string.

Comment: `s << x` may and almost certainly does allocate memory internally, but it should be transparent to you, unless you're extremely low on free memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code is OK, read the comments on the code:

```
std::string dtos(double x) {
    std::stringstream s;  // Allocates memory on stack
    s << x;
    return s.str();       // returns a s.str() as a string by value
                          // Frees allocated memory of s
}
```

In addition, you can pass a `double` to `cout` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised no one mentioned this, but you could genarlize that algorithm for any type, using templates.

Like so:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& obj)
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << obj;
    return s.str();
}
```

That way you can easily convert to a string, like so:

```
int x = 5;
to_string(x); // will convert the integer to a string

to_string(32); // constants works
to_string<double>(302); // you can explicitly type the type you wish to convert
```

Example usage is on this [link](http://ideone.com/C2WLOE).

Also, as stated by other people, there's no memory going anywhere. Also, I would like to mention, that since you're only writing to a string stream, perhaps you should use [std::ostringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/) for (1) further clarification when people read your code and (2) no mistakes of using >> instead of <<

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change doubles to strings to use `std::cout`.

```
cout << x;
```

will work just fine as

```
cout << dtos(x);
```

And if you want to change double to string for other reasons then you can use you can use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) in C++11.

Other than that your code is just fine.

Comment: No! he can not return `s` instead of `s.str()`, since `s` has a different type.

Comment: @ahhh you are right I don't know why I thought it was string.

Comment: @names, sorry I meant manipulating strings eg. x + s + "\n" etc. std::cout obviously works with doubles, it was building new strings I was having problems with. Bring on C++11! It seems so many niggly C++ issues that require extra lines of code are solved clearly with this version.

Comment: @Pete855217 then your code is just fine. If you have C++11 support just use `std::to_string`. Otherwise you are good.